# .Net OData - Manually get metadata entity URL

Tags: c#, .net, odata

I have a question, I'm using OData and I'm doing it manually. That is, I am using `ODataQueryOptions<Order>` as a parameter and then the `ApplyTo` method. However, I would like to add a metadata reference as well I mean - https://localhost:5001/api/odata/$metadata#Order. Is there any way to do this please? I can't seem to find it.

```
public virtual SomeDto Handle(ODataQueryOptions<Order> query)
{
    var result = new SomeDto();

    // result.ContextUrl = request.....?; //https://localhost:5001/api/odata/$metadata#Order
    result.Items = request.Query.ApplyTo(dbQuery).ToList();

    return result;
}
```